# I can't make jquery scroll pane horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jscrollpane

I have been using the following code successfully to make a vertical scroll bar with scroll pane:

```
function scrollPane(){
    $('.custom-scroll').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: true,
        verticalDragMinHeight : 0,
        verticalDragMaxHeight : 100,
        mouseWheelSpeed: 120,
        wheelSpeed: 120,
        contentWidth: '100px'
    });
}
```

I am now trying to make a horizontal scrollbar, but it is not working.  Here is my code:

```
function scrollPane(){
    $('.custom-scroll').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: true,
        verticalDragMinHeight : 0,
        verticalDragMaxHeight : 100,
        mouseWheelSpeed: 120,
        wheelSpeed: 120,
        contentWidth: '100px'
    });
    $('.horizontal_bar').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: true,
        contentWidth: '100px'
    });
}
```

and this is the only css i have for horizontal_bar:

```
.horizontal_bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

How do I make the horizontal scroll pane?